# LARAVEL: Class 'Articulo' not found

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código y  el siguiente modelo y no me conecta, me da error

```
//Eloquent
Route::get("/leer", function(){

    $articulos=Articulo::all();

    foreach($articulos as $articulo){

        echo $articulo->Nombre_Articulo."Precio: ".$articulo->Precio."<br>";

        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que importar la clase, utilizando la palabra `use`, idealmente al comienzo del archivo (dentro de la etiqueta php):

```
use App\Articulo;
```

Más información en la documentación de PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 0):

La clase artículo que hace referencia al modelo con el mismo nombre existe bajo el contexto del namespace `App\`.

Entonces cuando lo usas necesitas declarar su importación en la parte superior de esta forma:

```
use App\TuModelo;
```